# Scroll Spy Get Stuck on top, doesn't follow the scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am copying the exact same code and resources from http://getbootstrap.com/components

However, I don't understand why only in my copy, whenever I refresh the page, the entire ul list will get stuck in its position, therefore, if I scroll down, the ul will go off the screen.

This is my version:

[Scroll Spy Get Stuck](http://www.jibo-store.com/1028749119/)

If I do not refresh, the ul works as it should and follow wherever I scroll with the submenu being highlighted... The JQuery that set the `active` class seems to be working as the submenu with `active` class is correct. I have no idea at all how this could happen... any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

NOTE:

- -. It works on the original site
- -. It works on chrome
- -. Bootstrap 2.3.2 version works fine

Comment: It works fine for me on Chrome, but I see what you mean on Firefox. This seems like a bug in Bootstrap; does version 2.3.2 work any better?

Comment: oh, I didn't check on Chrome, thanks for noting. But it works fine on firefox on the original site :(

Comment: the 2.3.2 version works! I'll just revert to that, thanks!